# Count rows number by group and subgroup when some subgroup factor is 0

Tags: sas

I know how to count group and subgroup numbers through `proc freq` or sql. My question is when some factor in the subgroup is missing, and I still want to show missing factor as 0. How can I do that? For example,
the data set is:

```
group1 group2
1      A
1      A
1      A
1      A
2      A
2      B
2      B
```

I want a result as:

```
group1 group2 N
1      A      4
1      B      0
2      A      1
2      B      2
```

If I only use the default SAS setting, it will usually show as

```
group1 group2 N
1      A      4
2      A      1
2      B      2
```

But I still want to the second line in the result tell to me that there are 0 observations in that category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reeza's `sparse` option works as long as each group is represented in your data at least once. Suppose there were a group1 3 that is not represented in your data, and you would still want them to show up in the frequency table. If that is the case, the solution is to create a reference table with all of your categories then right join your frequency table to it.

Create a reference table:

```
data ref;
  do group1 = 1 to 3;
    group2 = 'A';
    output;
    group2 = 'B';
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Create the frequency table with proc sql, right joining to the reference table:

```
proc sql;
select
  r.group1,
  r.group2,
  count(h.group1) as freq
from
  have h
  right join ref r
  on h.group1 = r.group1
  and h.group2 = r.group2
group by
  r.group1,
  r.group2
order by
  r.group1,
  r.group2
;
quit;
```

Comment: When working with large datasets, I prefer the proc-based approaches to doing the summarisation, as they avoid doing any sorting/indexing.

Answer (score 6):

Use the SPARSE option within proc freq. Consider it a cross join between all options from GROUP1 and GROUP2.

```
data have;
input group1 group2 $;
cards;
1 A
1 A
1 A
1 A
2 A
2 B
2 B
;
run;

proc freq data=have;
table group1*group2/out=want sparse;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option that's a cross between DWal's issue of "what if the data isn't in the data" and Reeza's One Proc, One Solution, is `proc tabulate`.  If the *format* contains all possible values, even if the values don't appear, it works, with `printmiss`.

```
proc format;
value groupformat
    1='Group 1'
    2='Group 2'
    3='Group 3'
    ;
quit;

data have;
input group1 group2 $;
cards;
1 A
1 A
1 A
1 A
2 A
2 B
2 B
;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class group1 group2/preloadfmt;
  format group1 groupformat.;
  tables group1*group2,n/printmiss misstext='0';
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

How to do this via proc summary, using DWal's reference table to specify which combinations of values to use:

```
data ref;
  do group1 = 1 to 3;
    group2 = 'A';
    output;
    group2 = 'B';
    output;
  end;
run;

data have;
input group1 group2 $1.;
cards;
1 A
1 A
1 A
1 A
2 A
2 B
2 B
;
run;

proc summary nway data = have classdata=ref;
    class group1 group2;
    output out = summary (drop = _TYPE_);
run;
```

N.B. I had to tweak the `have` dataset slightly to make sure that group2 has length 1 in both datasets. If you use variables with the same name but different lengths in your `classdata=` and `data=` datasets, SAS will complain.